# How to query xml across multiple rows in SQLServer 2008R2

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery

In a table, I have multiple rows, each containing xml based on common schema. An example of the XML might be:

```
<Items>
    <Item>Item 1</Item>
    <Item>Item 2</Item>
</Items>
```

If I have multiple rows in a table, all containing similar xml, is it possible to write a query that returns all values in the `Item` node for all rows, in a single resultset? We're using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Is the column defined as `XML` datatype?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your xml is defined in an `XML` column ..

```sql
DECLARE @Items AS TABLE 
(
    ItemXml XML
)

-- test data with a couple rows of xml
INSERT INTO @Items(ItemXml)
VALUES ('<Items><Item>Item 1</Item><Item>Item 2</Item></Items>')
      ,('<Items><Item>Item 3</Item><Item>Item 4</Item></Items>')

-- the query
SELECT t.i.value('.','VARCHAR(8000)') AS Item
FROM @Items CROSS APPLY ItemXml.nodes('/Items/Item') t(i)
```

Will give you

```
Item
------
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
```

The key here is [`nodes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282(v=sql.105)) which

> is useful when you want to shred an xml data type instance into
>   relational data. It allows you to identify nodes that will be mapped
>   into a new row.